# From MySql to PostgreSql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I migrated this code from MySql to PostgreSql

```
function f_nome($e_tipo, $db_table)
{
    $thisyear = date('Y');
    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=**** user=yyyyy");
    $result = pg_query($db,"SELECT  MIN(data) AS earliest, nome, data, saldo, id
    FROM $db_table 
    WHERE tipo = '$e_tipo' AND year ='$thisyear'
    GROUP BY nome, data, saldo, id
    ORDER BY earliest");
    $row_cnt = pg_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
      {$z_nome=$row['nome'];
      echo "<option>$z_nome</option>";} 
pg_close($db);
return $z_nome; 
}
```

In MySql I obtain what I need (`$row_cnt = 12`) while in Postgres I get multiple times the same results.

In the DB I newad to read there are active and ceased items. Every week active items are updated. 
I want to read the last active updated items then with another script I create some graphs and stats.

How can I solve my problem with PG?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of using the low-level database driver directly, try and use something like PDO. If you use placeholders, that will also plug up those scary [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) you have here.

Comment: Please show the exact query run after parameter substitution and the output of it being run in `psql`. Without the data or the exact query it's hard to tell. Also, @tadman is right, that code is terrifyingly insecure script-kiddie bait, you should immediately switch to using `pg_query_params` then consider using something like PDO down the track; see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You are right but I dont need to use PDO since everything works on a local machine and only the printouts are shown to people.

Comment: Sorry but pressed "Enter" without completing the post. 
The expanded query is the following

`SELECT  MIN(data) AS earliest, nome, data, saldo, id
FROM stefano2012 WHERE tipo = 'Assicurativi' AND year ='2015' 
GROUP BY nome, data, saldo, id ORDER BY earliest `

while the result is here http://www.filedropper.com/query_1

Comment: @JoshuaWhopper PDO is just all around better. It gives you simpler tools to do the same job, and the same driver works with different back-ends. The only people I see using the `pg` low-level driver directly are those that don't know about PDO, or people writing their own ORM. It's just not intended to be used by your average developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your query is incorrect as you you include "data" in the GROUP BY clause, and at the same time you're trying to find the min(data). Essentially you will get not the minimum but the same data. I mean, if you have rows like

```
1 '10.07.2015' 'sdfg' 24
1 '10.07.2015' 'sdfg' 24
1 '10.07.2015' 'sdfg' 24
1 '11.07.2015' 'sdfg' 24
```

then you will get

```
'10.07.2015' 'sdfg' '10.07.2015' 1 24
'11.07.2015' 'sdfg' '11.07.2015' 1 24
```

as a result of your query. If you want to really find the min(data) then you should consider excluding "data" from the GROUP BY. Or what was your purpose?